# Ubuntu compilers (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++

I am new for Linux programming (Ubuntu server).

What difference between instructions:

```
c++ -c  main.cpp -o main.o -lstdc++
c++ -c  Console.cpp -o Console.o -lstdc++
c++ main.o Console.o -o App1
```

and this:

```
g++ -c  main.cpp -o main.o -lstdc++
g++ -c  Console.cpp -o Console.o -lstdc++
g++ main.o Console.o -o App1
```

Are these instructions the same? Is c++ instruction provides another name for g++?

Comment: Why do you specify -lstdc++ on the compile command line? It would only make sense on the linking line, but libstdc++ is assumed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update-alternatives --display c++`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, default is g++. You can check it using `update-alternatives --display c++`; change it via `sudo update-alternatives c++`

```
update-alternatives --config c++
There are 2 choices for the alternative c++ (providing /usr/bin/c++).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/g++       20        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/clang++   10        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/g++       20        manual mode
```

Answer (score 2):

They both use the GNU C++ compiler I believe.  So yes, they are the same.

Comment: `c++` can be linked to `g++`, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

They are probably the same. You can check explicitly:

> which c++
>
> /usr/bin/c++
>
> ls -l /usr/bin/c++
>
> /etc/alternatives/c++
>
> ls -l etc/alternatives/c++
>
> /usr/bin/g++

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same, typing

```
which c++
```

gives you that `c++` is in fact `/usr/bin/c++`. then typing

```
ll /usr/bin/c++
```

will give you

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Sep  4 17:00 /usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++*
```

then

```
ll /etc/alternatives/c++
```

will give you

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep  4 17:00 /etc/alternatives/c++ -> /usr/bin/g++*
```

so yes, they are the same (there is a symbolic link from c++ to g++).

Comment: This is just the default, `/etc/alternatives/c++` doesn't have to point to `/usr/bin/g++`.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for yourself:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/c++ /usr/bin/g++ /etc/alternatives/c++
```

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Jun  2 19:41 /etc/alternatives/c++ -> /usr/bin/g++*
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 Jun  2 19:41 /usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++*
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Mär 13  2012 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.6*

or do:

```
$ c++ -v
```

vs.

```
$ g++ -v
```

Answer (score 1):

`g++` means the GNU C++ compiler.

`c++` means a non-specific C++ compiler but it has to be linked to a specific one. If in your case, this is just a symbolic link to the GNU C++ compiler then there is no difference. However you could make the symbolic link point to a different C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**Here's how to figure out these types of things**

To find the path to an executable:

```
which c++
```

To check if it's a file or a symbolic link:

```
ls -ald `which c++`
```

To check what type of file it is:

```
file `which c++`
```

To get a checksum that can be used to compare it to other files:

```
md5sum `which c++`
```

Here's one way of checking if c++ and g++ are equal:

```
[ `md5sum $(which c++) | cut -d' ' -f1` == `md5sum $(which g++) | cut -d' ' -f1` ] && echo Yes, equal content || echo No, unequal content
```